# How to pass a char array element to a function in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, char, element

I need to pass a single element of a char array from int main to a function. This should pass a single char to the array. Not the whole array or anything. I've tried converting it into a single char (IE, char herps = charArray[1];) and then passing it to the function as herps, but it actually gives the same error, even when I know it's one piece of it.

The function must be string herp(char); . The array contains spaces and whatnot.

This gives me the error 'invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*''

Source code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    string toMorse(char);

    string toMorse(char letter){
    return "herp";
    }

    int main()
    {const int SIZE = 10;
    char line[SIZE];
    cin.getline(line, SIZE);
    int count=10;
    string toMorse(line[count]);
    return 0;}
```

Comment: *but it actually gives the same error* -- What error?

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of herp()?

Comment: I went ahead and updated with the relevant parts of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is declared as

char charArray[SOME_SIZE];

then calling a function declared as

```
string myFunc(char c);
```

via

```
myFunc(charArray[index]);
```

Will not give you an error.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string toMorse(char);

string toMorse(char letter){

}

int main()
{const int SIZE = 10;
char line[SIZE];
cin.getline(line, SIZE);
int count=10;
string toMorse(line[count]);
return 0;}

gives me the error 'invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*''

EDIT:MEANT TO INCLUDE SOURCE, ENTER SUBMITTED IT.

Comment: @user1896606, All three pieces of this code definitely won't.

Comment: Just posted a bare-bones version of the code that definitely does.

Comment: @user1896606, Ignoring the lack of `#include <string>` and the lack of a returned value from the function, that's a completely different sample than in the answer. You're initializing a `std::string` with a `char`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that missing header and return value, accidentally snipped them out. How am I initializing a string with a char? The goal is to pass a single letter out of the char array to the function. I can read out a single char in int main, but I can't pass them into the function for some reason.

Comment: You guys are correct. I'm a huge dumbass. I AM calling it as a string. string should not go in that line at all. Thank you so much OTL .

Answer (score 1):

In your main(),

```
string toMorse(line[count]);
```

you are not calling toMorse function, you are actually creating a string instance named toMorse, constructor gets called and looks for const char * as argument. 
Refer [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

You are creating a char array of size 10 and try to read 11th index, which is also wrong.

Modified Code:

```
   int main()
   {
    const int SIZE = 10;
    char line[SIZE];
    cin.getline(line, SIZE);
    int count=9; //Any whole number between 0 and SIZE-1 is acceptable.
    toMorse(line[count]);
    return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second last statement in your code that is posted, function call syntax is incorrect.
   string toMorse(line[count]); 
   needs to be replaced with 
   string returnString = toMorse(line[count]);
Or may be you want to just pass char than remove the "string" from that line.